# how to customize your action bar in Android Studio

Tags: android

How I can make changing in my Action Bar instead of making new toolbar, I just want to put logo and a Button in Action Bar.

[image: how i can make changing in my Action Bar instead of making new toolbar , i just want to put logo and a Button in Action Bar]

Comment: I recommend the [App Bar training guide](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html) from Android. I also recommend reading [ask] and [mcve] for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private Toolbar _toolbar;

private void setToolbarView(@StringRes int resTitle, @StringRes int resSubTitle, @DrawableRes int resLogo) {
    _toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    _toolbar.setTitle(resTitle);
    _toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    _toolbar.setSubtitle(resSubTitle);
    _toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    _toolbar.setLogo(resLogo);
    setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
}
```

**How to call setToolbarView() from onCreate()**

```
setToolbarView(R.string.toolbar_title, R.string.toolbar_subtitle, R.drawable.toolbar_logo);
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity">

    <!-- this is your toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarSubTitle"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**string.xml**

```
<string name="toolbar_title">This is title</string>
<string name="toolbar_subtitle">This is subtitle</string>
```

**drawable\toolbar_logo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_toolbar" <!-- this is png file --->
        android:right="16dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

**drawable\my_toolbar.png**

```
my_toolbar.png (hdpi)   
my_toolbar.png (mdpi)   
my_toolbar.png (xhdpi)  
my_toolbar.png (xxhdpi)
```

**How to generate my_toolbar.png**

- Rigt click on drawable folder
- New > Image Aset
- IconType == "Action Bar and tab Icons"
- Name == "my_toolbar"
- AssetType == "Image"
- Path == "Select your png files from your disk"
- Next > Finish